# TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm having an issue with my following JPA classes. When I try to query a `Customer` object, Hibernate gives me an `TypeMismatchException`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer", schema = "dbforq")
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CustomerId customerId;

    @OneToOne(optional = true, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, orphanRemoval = true, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ADDRESS_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_KEY", referencedColumnName = "ADDRESS_KEY", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private Address address;
}


@Embeddable
public class CustomerId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID", nullable = false)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_KEY")
    private String key;
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "address", schema = "dbforq")
public class Address implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private AddressId addressId;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")
    private Customer customer;
}


@Embeddable
public class AddressId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS_ID", nullable = false)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS_KEY")
    private String key;
}
```

The exception is as follows.

```
org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class my.package.dataaccess.objects.Address. Expected: class my.package.dataaccess.objects.AddressId, got class my.package.dataaccess.objects.CustomerId
```

What am I missing here? I'm using Spring Boot in version 2.3.1.

Comment: Perhaps your @JoinColumn mappings are backwards, because that would most likely cause you to have the wrong embedded id type.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more?

Answer (score 0):

I think what James Gawron meant is, have you tried this?

```
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "ADDRESS_ID", referencedColumnName = "CUSTOMER_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
    @JoinColumn(name = "ADDRESS_KEY", referencedColumnName = "CUSTOMER_KEY", insertable = false, updatable = false)
})
```